# OAuth exception error from Facebook access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, lumen, facebook-access-token, laravel-socialite

I am trying to build a REST API that will login to Facebook using socialite with lumen, a micro-service of Laravel. I have set up my Facebook app and configured the client_id, secret and access url accordingly.

The work flow is:
Here is the work flow

1.get user details from socialite

2.check the user existence with email ,if its exists execute auth::login, otherwise create a new record in users table and redirect to profile.

The program now redirects me to Facebook, however once the user presses the login button, it returns the following error:

```
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":*****,"f (truncated...)
```

I am confused as it has not been long since I generated the token and no user login/ permissions have changed, so the token should not be expired. Do I need to store the access token in a database in order to grant the user permission or is there some way to store it in a user's browser session?(I already have a database configured on forge for user name and email)

Comment: _“so the token should not be expired”_ - who said anything about a token being expired? The error message you quoted certainly doesn’t.

Comment: @CBroe How do I fix the authorisation code error was the main question. I was just emphasising that the access token was still valid.

Comment: Well you fix it by _not_ trying to exchange a `code`, that _has_ already been exchanged for a token, a second time … Why this currently happens, only you can possibly know, we haven’t been shown _any_ code.